# Call a function one time per day at a specific time Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer, delete-row

I have a tableview and I want to empty it at a specific time (the user enter in a picker) of the day everyday. Here is the code it mostly work, but lets say the user opened the app at 7pm and the update time is at 8pm the data is not deleted (which is correct) but when the time is at 9pm the same day and the app is opened the data is not deleted (which is incorrect). I think it is something to do with `lastRefreshDate` being updated evreytime time the app is opened and have to wait for 24hours from `lastRefreshDate` and not from the `userPickedHour`. The app should work like this there is a set time 7pm. So the app should delete the data the next day at 7pm or after 7pm when the user open the app but if the user open the app before 7pm the next day it should not delete the data,

Here is the code:

```
class RefreshManager: NSObject {

static let shared = RefreshManager()
private let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
private let defaultsKey = "lastRefresh"
private let calender = Calendar.current



func loadDataIfNeeded(completion: (Bool) -> Void) {

    if isRefreshRequired() {
        // load the data
        defaults.set(Date(), forKey: defaultsKey)
        print("xxxxxx")
        completion(true)
    } else {
        print("yyyyyy")
        completion(false)
    }
}

private func isRefreshRequired(userPickedHour: Int = 16) -> Bool {
    let SleepPickerdate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "SleepDate") as? Date
    let userPickedHour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: (SleepPickerdate)!)
    print(userPickedHour)

    guard let lastRefreshDate = defaults.object(forKey: defaultsKey) as? Date else {
        return true
    }

    if let diff = calender.dateComponents([.hour], from: lastRefreshDate, to: Date()).hour,
        let currentHour =  calender.dateComponents([.hour], from: Date()).hour,
        diff >= 24, userPickedHour >= currentHour {

        print("Delete TableView")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Delete"), object: nil)
        print(diff)
        return true

    } else {

        print("Don't Delete TableView")

        return false


      }
    }
  }



class ViewController: UIViewController {

let refreshManager = RefreshManager.shared

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    refreshManager.loadDataIfNeeded() { success in
        print(success)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Never calculate a date using time interval offset (e.g. 86400 seconds). Have you thought what would happen at the start / end of daylight savings?

Comment: I want that at the specific time of the day, lets say 4pm even if the app is closed when the user open the app at 5pm so after the time it would remove the data in tableview and wait for the other day at 4pm or after that when the user open the app the data to be deleted

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot guarantee that your app is running at that time, each day. the phone could of lost all of its battery power, app might not be running... etc etc.

But this is just a logical problem... If you want to refresh the data after a certain time each day, you should just store a last refresh time in UserDefaults, and if that time was more than your required expiry time (in this case 24h) then refresh the data and update the last updated time.

So if you have an active user, as soon as the 24 hour time difference expires it would refresh, or if a users phone was off for a few days (for whatever reason) your app would still know it needs to refresh the data once the user comes back to the app.

**EDIT: Added code example**

```
class RefreshManager: NSObject {

    static let shared = RefreshManager()
    private let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    private let defaultsKey = "lastRefresh"
    private let calender = Calendar.current

    func loadDataIfNeeded(completion: (Bool) -> Void) {

        if isRefreshRequired() {
            // load the data
            defaults.set(Date(), forKey: defaultsKey)
            completion(true)
        } else {
            completion(false)
        }
    }

    private func isRefreshRequired() -> Bool {

        guard let lastRefreshDate = defaults.object(forKey: defaultsKey) as? Date else {
            return true
        }

        if let diff = calender.dateComponents([.hour], from: lastRefreshDate, to: Date()).hour, diff > 24 {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

You don't really have to make this a new class or a singleton like I have. It was just easier to keep everything nicely contained for the sake of the answer.

So this will work that if there is no refresh date, or if the number of hours since the last one is greater than 24 then it will update the data and update the last refresh date/time. using the completion it will also return whether it updated data or not.

You could also add a check in here that the current hour of the day is `>= 16` if required.

**EDIT 2: User selectable hour**

```
private func isRefreshRequired(userPickedHour: Int = 16) -> Bool {

    guard let lastRefreshDate = defaults.object(forKey: defaultsKey) as? Date else {
        return true
    }

    if let diff = calender.dateComponents([.hour], from: lastRefreshDate, to: Date()).hour,
        let currentHour =  calender.dateComponents([.hour], from: Date()).hour,
        diff >= 24, userPickedHour <= currentHour {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

In this modified isRefreshRequired function you can pass a value for the hour and see whether it has been at least 24 hours since the last refresh and that the current hour is or is greater than the users selected hour.

This doesn't mean it will run at say for example exactly 16:00 by the way. it will run when the user loads that screen and the rules pass (min 24 hours passed, currentHour is >= userSelected hour)

**EDIT 3: how to call**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let refreshManager = RefreshManager.shared

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        refreshManager.loadDataIfNeeded() { success in
            print(success)
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Changed logic**

```
if let diff = calender.dateComponents([.day], from: lastRefreshDate, to: Date()).day,
    let currentHour =  calender.dateComponents([.hour], from: Date()).hour,
    diff >= 1, userPickedHour <= currentHour {
    return true
} else {
    return false
}
```

Comment: hey, so what should `last refresh time`be I want that at the specific time of the day, lets say 4pm even if the app is closed when the user open the app at 5pm so after the time it would remove the data in tableview and wait for the other day at 4pm or after that when the user open the app the data to be deleted

Comment: Do you mind updating your answer with a code reponse

Comment: I have added an example in the answer, hope it helps

Comment: Hey, should I call `isRefreshRequired()` in viewDidLoad ? also I want the hour of the update to be the user selected time so should I replace `calender.dateComponents([.hour] ` with  `Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: (sleepPickerdate)!)`

Comment: also where should I call `loadDataIfNeeded`

Comment: You dont need to call isRefreshRequired, in the code I used its private and already called by loadDataIfRequired. Also in my code above I have specified a time of day or an hour to do the update. the line that starts with `calender.dateComponents([.hour] ` only works out the difference between last refresh date and now. nothing to do with hour of the day, we just saying how many hours have passed between these two date times

Comment: Okay thanks, so the `lastRefreshDate` should be the user `sleepPickerdate` and should I call loadDataIfNeeded in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yes you can call in viewDidLoad. I have updated the answer again with an example of how you could pass a user selected hour in. if none passed it will default to 16 (4pm)

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you, just one question calling `loadDataIfNeeded(completion: (Bool) -> Void)` I get the error can not convert of type bool is there a specific way I should call it in viewDidLoad

Comment: when calling it do `loadDataIfNeeded { success in //your code here }` see trailing closures documentation here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html. if this solves your issue please mark an answer as accepted

Comment: yes sure, but the `loadDataIfNeeded() { success in}` I am having the error cannot convert of type (bool -> void).type to (bool -> void)

Comment: just get rid of this part, you dont really need it. was just a bonus `completion: (Bool) -> Void` in the loadDataIfRequired and remove any calls to completion. I'll update the code with a working call

Comment: I've updated the answer with a view controller calling this method without any errors like you are getting

Comment: Hey, I tested the code it mostly work, but lets say the user opened the app at 7pm and the update time is at 8pm the data is not deleted (which is correct) but when the time is at 9pm the same day and the app is opened the data is not deleted (which is incorrect). I think it is something to do with `lastRefreshDate` being updated evreytime time the app is opened and have to wait for 24hours from `lastRefreshDate` and not from the `userPickedHour`. The app should work like this there is a set time 7pm. So the app should delete the data the next day at 7pm or after 7pm when the user open the app

Comment: you could change the logic, rather than checking for 24h, check that is has not been refreshed today already and currentHour is >= user hour. that should work for you

Comment: I have updated with an example, might still need some tweaks but should give you enough information.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the updated code, tried it it works the only problem is lets say the userPickedHour is 7pm in order to get the data deleted the app should be opened the next day at 7pm if it is opened at say 9pm it dosent get the data deleted

Comment: I dont see why not, the `.day` difference would be 1 and the userPickedHour would be 19 and currentHour would be 21. so both conditions are met

Comment: Yep but in the code `userPickedHour >= currentHour` but in this case userPickedHour is smaller than currentHour.

Comment: How? if userPickedHour is 19 and currentHour is 21?

Comment: 19 is 7pm and 21 is 9pm, so the condition becomes 19 >= 21 ?

Comment: ah i see... reverse the condition then to `<=`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use long-running timers like that in iOS. In fact you can't get your app to call a function at a specific time of day.

After a short time the user locks their phone and your app gets suspended to save battery power.

There is no way to do what you are asking to do unless you're writing for a jailbroken phone.

### EDIT:

You said "I just want when the user opens the app after the specific time to see that tableview data is deleted."

> Ok, that's different. When the app is open, calculate the date at which you want the records to be deleted.

Save that date to `UserDefaults`. Then implement an `applicationDidBecomeActive()` method, and in that method, read the saved date from UserDefaults, and if it has passed, delete the data that you display in your table view.

Comment: Hey, I dont want to delete the data in background, I just want when the user opens  the app after the specific time to see that tableview data is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

## Simple Sample

For example, We can set the next updated date in "lastRefresh", so, when that date pass, then It will refresh it again set date for the next refresh.

```
class RefreshManager: NSObject {

static let shared = RefreshManager()
private let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
private let defaultsKey = "lastRefresh"
private let calender = Calendar.current

func loadDataIfNeeded(completion: (Bool) -> Void) {
    if isRefreshRequired() {
        var date = Date()
        
        //Check for duration (Daily, Weekly or Monthly) (0,1,2)
        switch SaveManager.shared.user()!.UserShare.duration {
        case 0:
            //If user want to share daily
            date = date.addComponentsToDate(seconds: 0, minutes: 0, hours: 0, days: 1, weeks: 0, months: 0, years: 0)
            break
            
        case 1:
            //If user want to share weekly
            date = date.addComponentsToDate(seconds: 0, minutes: 0, hours: 0, days: 0, weeks: 1, months: 0, years: 0)
            break
            
        case 2:
            //If user want to share monthly
            date = date.addComponentsToDate(seconds: 0, minutes: 0, hours: 0, days: 0, weeks: 0, months: 1, years: 0)
            break
            
        default:
            //If user want to share daily : Default
            date = date.addComponentsToDate(seconds: 0, minutes: 0, hours: 0, days: 1, weeks: 0, months: 0, years: 0)
            break
        }

        date = date.startOfDay
        defaults.set(date, forKey: defaultsKey)
        print(date.toString())
        
        completion(true)
    } else {
        completion(false)
    }
}

private func isRefreshRequired() -> Bool {
    guard let lastRefreshDate = defaults.object(forKey: defaultsKey) as? Date else {
        return true
    }
    
    if lastRefreshDate.isLaterThanOrEqualTo(date: Date()) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}}
```